# Why model in Entity Framework 6 can not serialize the data?

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, serialization

I try to get data from model and pass to client with json format. I wrote this code but when execute the code, I get an internal server error. When debugging code, data is shown such as this image.

[image]

Please advice.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCity(int idCountry)
{
    TravelEnterAdminTemplate.Models.LG.MyJsonResult myresult = new Models.LG.MyJsonResult();

    try
    {
        List<City> citylist = new List<City>();
        var citystable = db.Cities.Where(p => p.CountryId == idCountry).ToList();

        if (citystable != null)
        {
            foreach (var city in citystable)
            {
                myresult.obj = citystable;     
            }
            myresult.Result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            myresult.Result = false;
            myresult.message = "داده ای یافت نشد";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errorlog.Error("DeleteShopping", "157", e.Source.ToString(), e.Message);
        myresult.Result = false;
        myresult.message = "خطا در بارگذاری اطلاعات";
    }

    return Json(myresult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

City Entity :

```
namespace TravelEnterAdminTemplate.Models.dbModel
```

{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class City
{
    public City()
    {
        this.ArtPlaces = new HashSet<ArtPlace>();
        this.Historicals = new HashSet<Historical>();
        this.Hospitals = new HashSet<Hospital>();
        this.Hotels = new HashSet<Hotel>();
        this.PhotoTables = new HashSet<PhotoTable>();
        this.PhotoTables1 = new HashSet<PhotoTable>();
        this.Restaurants = new HashSet<Restaurant>();
        this.Shoppings = new HashSet<Shopping>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameFA { get; set; }
    public string NameEN { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArtPlace> ArtPlaces { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Historical> Historicals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hospital> Hospitals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhotoTable> PhotoTables { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhotoTable> PhotoTables1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shopping> Shoppings { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you, please, pot here City entity. An would not recommend you to send entities to client, you should better create view model, convert entities to models and than send models instead

Comment: this entity is quite complex, most probably it contains some circular references which prevent object to be serialized. Try to use POCO template it might help you, if not than just create model and workwith it instead of entity

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Read this article http://www.strathweb.com/2012/03/serializing-entity-framework-objects-to-json-in-asp-net-web-api/, it should be helpful